# Не могу скомпилировать исходные файлы C++ Ошибка BC2008 Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Я скачал исходный файл программы HE4HOOK и создал проект используя имеющиеся исходный код в Visual Studio. Установил Net Framework 4… и сейчас выдает ошибку BC2008 не задано входящих источников. Убедитесь в том что включен файл исходного кода. Что мне делать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Может глупо вышло, но у меня в действиях при сборки стояло Содержание вместо компиляции, у меня только один вопрос.. Какого студия не выставила автоматом этот пункт! Я же настроил проект как исходный код на c++ и она автоматом должна была понять что делать при сборке